# Rails 3 + Devise error in migration: undefined method timeoutable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails 3 and Devise 1.3.4 for authentication in my app. 
After generating the user model, I try to add more devise modules to my devise_create_users.rb migration file, but I get the error:
undefined method `timeoutable' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition.

However, adding other modules like :confirmable work just fine.

devise_create_user.rb:

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.database_authenticatable :null => false
  t.recoverable
  t.rememberable
  t.trackable
  t.timeoutable
  # t.encryptable
  t.confirmable
  # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
  # t.token_authenticatable


  t.timestamps
end
```

My user model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable , :timeoutable
# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Any ideas what the error could be?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you don't actually need any migration for timeoutable, it's just a declaration on the user/resource class. See
[How do I add Devise's 'timeoutable' module to an existing Devise install? - Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520195/how-do-i-add-devises-timeoutable-module-to-an-existing-devise-install-rail)

Answer (score 1):

Do 'rails g devise:install' instead of 'rails g devise install' then migrate db then it should work

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the migration file after running for the first time? 
Can you please make sure that the users table is having all the columns specified in the devise_create_user.rb

Comment: Hi Arun, I edited the file before running any migration. After i got the timeoutable error,I commented out the line and run the migration again. This time it was successful and my table has all the columns for : database_authenticatable, recoverable, rememberable,trackable and confirmable.