# How do I add Devise's 'timeoutable' module to an existing Devise install? - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

These are the instructions to add a module to an existing Devise install: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns

But I can't seem to locate the necessary columns for `timeoutable`.

I looked for the fields that `timeoutable` requires in the Devise library: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/schema.rb - but there is no such method in that schema file.

The model just has a custom method with no reference to the columns: http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable

How do I add that functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first link gave all the answers! thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`timeoutable` refers to the login session timeout. No extra columns are needed, just add it to your model.

The `timeoutable` hook contains all the magic (source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb)

Comment: No columns are required because the time of the user's last request is stored in the session.

Answer (score 29):

You only need add `timeoutable` to your user model:

```
devise :timeoutable
```

And set the interval time in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
# ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
# The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
# time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
```

Comment: You also need to ensure you've run the correct migration to add the column to the database.

Comment: :timeoutable doesn't require any extra columns. See answer above.

Comment: I tried to put it right away, but looking at the code I see that the column last_request_at is read so if you don't have it you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your model:

```
devise :timeoutable, timeout_in: XX.minutes
```

replace XX with the number of minutes you want.

Answer (score 0):

`timeoutable` not working if you are have `remember_me = true`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb#L26